# Synchronization between SQL Server and SQL Server CE with only related data

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm new to Microsoft SyncOrchestrator.

I have 2 tables. with 1 to many relationship.

- Parent table has values (a, b, c, d)
- Child table has (a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, d1, d2, d3, d4)

When synchronizing, in parent table, only `a, c, d` is synchronised, using a filter.

My problem is, how to sync only (`a1,a2,a3,c1,d1,d2,d3,d4`) in child table (must not sync any data related to (b)

[Click here to see the flow...](https://picasaweb.google.com/100656584770088564642/Sync?authkey=Gv1sRgCL_7rpTXzpKf7AE#5888841174118072722)

Answer (score 0):

assuming a, c and d are known values, you can add a filter on the child table with an IN clause...

e.g., parentId IN (a, c, d)

how did you add the filter on the parent table anyway?

Comment: hi,thank for reply.By adding a filter Column. eg. serverTemplate.Tables["Master_Item"].AddFilterColumn("IsActive");
                serverTemplate.Tables["Master_Item"].FilterClause = "[side].[IsActive] = @IsActive ";

Comment: you can add the same filter parameter to the child table and put the filter clause as "parentId IN (select parentId from Master_Item where IsActive = @IsActive)".